Any way to make a Dropdown scene selector in Unity?
I'm trying to make one of my script (the one that controls where the place should go (switch scene) once collided), and while I got the base stuff right, unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to make it changable via a drop down menu via the Inspector.
My code for reference:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelSwap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string level_to_load = "Stage2";     // <-- It needs to be editable in the Editor otherwise a bunch of scripts doing the same thing

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(level_to_load);
        }
    }
}

This is primarily to prevent unnecessary script duplication.
Any help would be nice.

A dropdown would require a custom inspector for the LevelSwap class. That's possible, but an alternative would be to make level_to_load into a Scene instead of a string, so Unity would only show scenes when picking an object.

@ipodtouch0218 nope actually unfortunately not! Scene is not serializable and SceneAsset is only available within the editor ... so you can't just reference a scene asset in an inspector that easily. There is a simple editor script (see duplicate link) that enables this though! It basically serializes the scene path as a string but in the Inspector exposes a field you can reference scene assets in.
